# Vim команда "syntax enable/on". Что лучше?

Tags: vim, vimrc

Не могу определиться, какую команду использовать в `vimrc` для включения подсветки синтаксиса: `syntax enable` или `syntax on`. С одной стороны, в `syntax.txt` предлагается использовать `enable`, но в файле `$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim` используется `on`. Кроме того симметричной команды `syntax disable` нет, а `syntax off` есть.

Если я правильно понимаю, с `enable` сохраняются текущие настройки подсветки, и это вся разница.

Еще, для временного переключения подсветки я использую мапинг `nnoremap <silent> <F4> :if exists("g:syntax_on") <Bar> syntax off <Bar> else <Bar> syntax on <Bar> endif<CR>`, в котором использую `on/off`.

Так какой способ более "правильный", `enable` или `on`?

Comment: Не все так однозначно https://stackoverflow.com/a/33380495/644688

Comment: Есть мнение, что фраза "The ":syntax enable" command will keep your current color settings" в `:h *:syn-enable*` относится к расцветке синтаксиса, а не ко всем цветам. По крайней мере, у меня в _vimrc_ выше `syntax on` есть команда `hi StatusLine ctermbg=Black ctermfg=Yellow`, и на неё `syntax on` не влияет.